# Problem when trying to shrink part of model (with armature) - IK

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, inverse-kinematics

I have problem with armature and bones and due to my lack of knowledge about all this stuff I'll try to explain as good as possible. This is simple model I have a problem with.

[image]

Course, all work is based on single "leg" and later duplicated and rotated properly seven more times. Each leg has three parts (base, middle and tip) and each part is parented to single bone of armature (as `bone`). I've set **Inverse Kinematics** constraint to the tip bone to control entire leg and it works fine. I've also added additional empty (cube) and parented it to armature for easier control (see image below)

[image]

My problem is base part (next image). I want to allow the front part to be pulled into the spherical part (by scaling the cylinder, or simply, by pulling the front part into the ball).

[image]

I need to be able to do same things in both case, with short and full-length cylinder. I've tried adding additional bone on cylinder and using scale. I'm ending up with entire front part of leg being scaled, or if I lock scale for these objects, I'm loosing rotation points on bone-joints.

I need this.

Any idea how to fix this?

**UPDATE:**

---

After @Crantisz's suggestion it finally works in the way I like.

[image]

Comment: Are you wanting the scaling to be controlled by the IK system, or manually?  Controlled by IK is complicated (there will be multiple IK solutions, making twitch or undesired behavior likely) but manual is simple enough-- you can simply increase base's Y location transform (not move in normal Y, not quite the same thing.)

Comment: @Nathan Well, anything working is good enough for me coz I'm noob at all this. Is it possible to change location of that part of object and shorten that bone that's controlling base. It's not good if I move part of object and rest stays in place so I have gap between base and mid part.

Comment: It sounds like you got it worked out, but assuming that further bones are parented, which they'd need to be for IK to be working, they'll all follow.

Comment: @Nathan, Yeah, that tiny **Inherit Scale** option was a life saver. I've updated my question with final result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bone after that's going to be scaled, you can set **Inherit Scale** to **None**:

[image]

So that bone after scaled gets rotation and location, but not the scale.

Works with IK to: [image]

Comment: Sounds good. Haven't noticed that option. Let me try this.

Comment: Nope, still the same... Entire front part (both, parented objects and bones) are scaling up or down together with that bone. Is it possible that IK causes that option not to work properly (because I need tip bone to be start of IK chain).

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I've set that to wrong bone, you said **bone after**. Yeah, it's working now! Thanx a million.

Comment: Tell me, is it possible somehow to set empty and connect to that bone, to apply scaling outside of pose mode. That way I dont need to enter pose mode for armature of each legs and do separate adjusting.

Comment: Yep, of course, you have to learn about drivers in Blender.